# Preferred Scala collection for progressively removing random items?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have an algoritm which takes many iterations, each of which scores items in a collection and removes the one with the highest score.

I could populate a `Vector` with the initial population, continually replacing it as a `var`, or choose a mutable collection as a `val`. Which of the mutable collections would best fit the bill?

Comment: Does the order of items matter?

Comment: Yes - they are in a priority order, but then I have to pick the highest priority that meets other criteria, so we may work some way down the list before finding the one to remove.

Comment: Approximately how many iterations and how large is the initial collection? Does the process run until there is only one element left in the collection or are there many more elements than iterations?

Comment: Oh and is the scoring function costly to compute?

Comment: Another question to ask is whether you really need to remove the elements *immediately*, or whether you can just *ignore* the scored elements and then do a batch clean-up at some point.

Comment: The collection is of orders for files to be delivered, and the scoring will depend on which have already been delivered previously. Maybe 5000 orders, and it may be that some are not able to be delivered on time and are left on the pile at the end.

Comment: @TechNeilogy leaving them in and marking as satisfied is a good idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider a [**`DoubleLinkedList`**](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/DoubleLinkedList.html), which has a convenient `remove()` method to remove the current list cell.

Comment: I hadn't seen DoubleLinkedList in my trawls - I think it best fits the general bill of ordered collection with cheap removal. If you remove the ListBuffer part I can accept the answer :-)

Comment: OK, I've had a chance to try this in anger, and in practice the complications of loosing the head mean that it's way more complicated than it should be - you have to fall back to a holding the collection in a var.

Answer (score 4):

I think a `Map` (or its close relative, the `Set`) might do well. It doesn't have *indexed* access, but that doesn't seem to be what you want. If you go for a `TreeMap`, you'll even get an ordered collection.

However, might I point out that your algorithm seems to call for a [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)? A heap is optimized for repeatedly finding/removing the maximum element (or minimum, if you invert the the comparison building the heap). Scala doesn't have a ready made heap, but a heap is easily implemented with an array.

Comment: My problem is that the final score can't be precomputed, but I do have an initial ordering. Look into Heap when using DoubleLinkedList shows it's performance, thanks.

Comment: @dcsobral If you are referring to a binary heap, Scala has the `mutable.PriorityQueue` class which is exactly that.

Comment: `PriorityQueue` etc only let you pop items off the top rather than hunting through if you have other criteria. I thought of `TreeMap`, but it's not mutable. Not sure what the mutable counterpart is, but if no items are added subsequently, I don't see the advantage of a tree over a sorted `DoubleLinkedList`

Comment: @axel22 I didn't know it was implemented as a heap.