# What is the current element in a Scala DoubleLinkedList?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm looking at [using](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7760925/97777) a [DoubleLinkedList](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/DoubleLinkedList.html). It's remove() method says *"Removes the current node from the double linked list."* but there are no other references to *current* in the page.

What is the current node, how do I set it, and surely this can't be the only way of removing an item?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `DoubleLinkedList` is at the same time the list itself *and* a list node, similar to the `::` for a regular `List`. You can navigate from one cell to the next or to the previous one with `next` and `prev`, respectively, and get the value of a cell with `elem`.

```
scala> val list = collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList(1,2,3,4,5)
list: scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList[Int] = DoubleLinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> list.next.next.remove() // list.next.next points on 3rd cell

scala> list
res0: scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList[Int] = DoubleLinkedList(1, 2, 4, 5)
```

Be careful if you remove the first cell, as you’ll need to reassign your var holding the list to the next cell:

```
scala> val list = collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList(1,2,3,4,5)
list: scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList[Int] = DoubleLinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> list.remove() // remove first item

scala> list // this is now a 'dangling' cell, although it still points to the rest of the list
res6: scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList[Int] = DoubleLinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // uh? didn't I remove the first cell?

scala> list.next.prev // we can check that it is not pointed back to by its next cell
res7: scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList[Int] = null
```

Comment: Good answer - a bit of a shame the docs aren't as good as StackOverflow!

Comment: Is there a way to move back to the first without calling prev many times?

Comment: No, you have to keep calling `prev` until you find `null`.

Comment: The only thing missing from this answer is an example of replacing an item in the list with another item.  I believe that is as simple as list.insert(DoubleLinkedList(item)) and list.remove()